# How to tell TortoiseSVN that a renamed file was renamed (not deleted and re-added)?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Using VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN here.

I've renamed my file. I notice it say add and delete which to me means history may be erased?

What is the best way to rename a file without losing history in Subversion?

Comment: You didn't indicate wether you want to rename it using VisualSvn (ie within Visual Studio) or TortoiseSvn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right Click on the file > TortoiseSVN > Rename.

Comment: visualsvn tag and the question might indicate that he already renamed with visualsvn, if that's the case it's correctly added (with history )/deleted (that's what a Subversion rename is)

Answer (score 27):

The history won't be erased, but you will lose history tracing, as it would seem to be two unrelated files.

From [**TortoiseSVN docs**](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html):

> If you want to do a simple in-place rename of a file or folder, use Context Menu → Rename...  Enter the new name for the item and you're done.
>
> Repairing File Renames
>
> Sometimes your friendly IDE will rename files for you as part of a refactoring exercise, and of course it doesn't tell Subversion. If you try to commit your changes, **Subversion will see the old filename as missing and the new one as an unversioned file. You could just check the new filename to get it added in, but you would then lose the history tracing, as Subversion does not know the files are related.**
>
> A better way is to notify Subversion that this change is actually a rename, and you can do this within the Commit and Check for Modifications dialogs. **Simply select both the old name (missing) and the new name (unversioned) and use Context Menu → Repair Move to pair the two files as a rename**.

Many other cases are covered.

**Update**

The history is lost when Subversion doesn't know it's a rename, like this:

- the old file name is **aa.txt**, and it's renamed by hand to **bb.txt**
- the new file name **bb.txt** is added to subversion
- in the commit dialog, **aa.txt** appears as **missing** and can be marked as **deleted**, and **bb.txt** appears as **added**
- the result is that history is lost, **SVN show log** from the contextual menu will show only **bb.txt**

To preserve file history, you need to use the **Rename** option from the contextual menu (or from the command line). **IF** you already renamed the file then:

- the old file name **cc.txt** will appear as missing
- check the **Show unversioned files** option to see the new file name **dd.txt**, which is marked as **non-versioned**
- select both file names and choose **Repair move** from the contextual menu, which results in **cc.txt** being marked as **deleted** and **dd.txt** being marked as **added (+)**
- after commit, history will be preserved, and in the log you will see both file names if you uncheck the **Stop on copy/rename** option.

So, to resume, in the commit dialog **added (+)** means that history will be preserved, and **added** means loosing the the history. In both cases, the old file name will appear as **deleted**.

**Update 2**

When I say that history is lost, please understand that the previous information still exists, but it won't be present in the log of the current file name, and you must manually track it (which is not quite a pleasant thing to do).

Comment: An even better way is to use a Subversion-aware IDE which will rename the files correctly...

Comment: An even better way is to use Git or Mercurial :D but sometimes you won't have a choice about the IDE and the other tools used.

Comment: @JesperE: he mentions he's using a Subversion-aware IDE plugin.

Comment: Let me see: he already renamed the file and subversion doesn't know it (quote: I notice it say add and delete), so I point him to the subversion docs and did some spoonfeeding - quoted the repairing procedure. So enlighten me: why the downvote?

Comment: add and delete is *exactly* what you see when you `svn move` a file

Comment: @Sander Rijken : unless the history is preserved and then you see deleted and added (+) in the commit dialog

Comment: Long story short, this entire post could have simply been reduced to this statement: "select both file names and choose Repair move from the context menu".  That's the beef.  That's what I learned today.

Comment: It was that dang "Stop on copy/rename" Checkbox Option after Right-Clicking and selecting "Show Log" History on the File.  Once I Unchecked it, it finally showed me the entire History of the file.  Was going crazy because I Renamed it using the Context-Menus and thought it still wasn't working.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

The history is not erased by doing a rename from the TortoiseSVN Context Menu. If you want to see the changes from before the rename, make sure you don't use the --stop-on-copy flag when looking at the change log:

```
svn log -v -r 0:N --limit 100 [--stop-on-copy] PATH
  or
svn log -v -r M:N [--stop-on-copy] PATH
```

see here for reference:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html

Comment: Thank you @Mike! We had a case where our root was renamed a couple of times, so it seemed that manual diff-by-url would be the only solution. (Blame is a bit painful for long files.) Ensuring in TortoiseSvn that stop on  copy was unchecked worked like a charm. Then one can choose start/end revisions in Show Log, Compare Revisions, See the list  of files, and Double-click to diff.

Answer (score 3):

The file's history will not be erased. Previous commits won't be affected. However, you can use `svn move` to properly move the file.

Answer (score 1):

For file operations like moving and renaming I normally prefer to use the [TortoiseSVN Repo Browser](http://wsmoak.net/subversion/demo/tsvn-repo-browser.html), followed by a local SVN Update. Of course that's only appropriate if you want your operation to be committed to the repository straight away.

Answer (score 0):

A delete and add with history is the expected thing to happen when renaming a file in Subversion. History is not lost.

VisualSvn and AnkhSvn both capture the events from Visual Studio that a file is being renamed, and do the right thing.