# SVN deleting renamed/repaired file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Scenario in VS2012, with VisualSVN.

- Right-click rename a file (using VS solution explorer)
- Hack for several hours
- Right-click commit project
- Right-click and [repair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2195448) the before/after versions of the file
- An 'error' box says "file can't be found"
- And yes, quite right, the NEW version of my file is gone.
- *(Expletives deleted)*

I know that SVN doesn't like not being the master of rename, but what's going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: *Right-click and repair the before/after versions of the file* - can you give some more info about this step?

Comment: @IvanJovovic, I pasted an image.

Comment: I have managed to reproduce the described issue, but nothing more. The exact error message is: *The system cannot find the file specified*.

Comment: Fixed. http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=3114142

Comment: If you are using VisualStudio, shouldn't you be using the VisualStudio Integration and not TortoiseSVN? I never used VisualSVN as a VisualStudio plugin, but it should work directly in VisualStudio. I've use [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net) as a VisualStudio integration and didn't have problems with renaming a file *inside VisualStudio*.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems to be a bug in TortoiseSVN. I've just reported it to [dev@ TortoiseSVN mailing-list](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=3114077). [**The bug has been just fixed. Thanks to Stefan Kung**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=3114142).
2. You don't need to run "Repair move" command on files that were *properly renamed or moved*. VisualSVN tracks all file operations performed in Visual Studio and reflects them to Subversion. Moves, adds, renames, etc -- these are all covered by VisualSVN plug-in.

Here is a quote from TortoiseSVN manual linked to your question:

> Sometimes your friendly IDE will rename files for you as part of a
>   refactoring exercise, and **of course it doesn't tell Subversion.**

VisualSVN actually *tells* Subversion that there was a rename, therefore you don't need to run "Repair move" when using VisualSVN.

Just try to rename a file in some testing Visual Studio solution using VisualSVN and check `svn status` to see what happened. For example, here is the result you'll see:

```
D       WindowsFormsApplication3\Program.cs
        > moved to WindowsFormsApplication3\SUPERPROGRAM.cs
A  +    WindowsFormsApplication3\SUPERPROGRAM.cs
        > moved from WindowsFormsApplication3\Program.cs
```

As you can see, the file has been properly renamed.

And here is the repository log entry for the rename after you commit the change:

```
r3 | Pavel.Lyalyakin | 2015-04-22 13:46:38 +0300 (Wed, 22 Apr 2015) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/WindowsFormsApplication3/Program.cs
   A /trunk/WindowsFormsApplication3/SUPERPROGRAM.cs (from /trunk/WindowsFormsApplication3/Program.cs:2)
```

As you can see, there is a note that the file SUPERPROGRAM.cs was renamed from Program.cs in revision 2.

Comment: Great, good to know I'm not crazy :) As an aside, I think the (+) notation is nuts, because it just looks like it's a synonym of Add. Couldn't they put 'renamed' there instead?

Comment: @Benjol not yet. I guess it will be improved when rename tracking will be implemented in future Subversion updates. It's on Subversion's roadmap http://subversion.apache.org/roadmap.html